# How can I specify VM properties (CPU, memory) for Azure pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our open-source project needs 4+ cpu cores to run its tests. How can I specify this in `azure-pipelines.yml`? By default, the VM is 2 cpu for `vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'`.

Comment: an obvious answer would be to use **self** hosted agent. I'm not sure this is possible with hosted agents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#capabilities-and-limitations) pretty much says you are limited to a specific VM size (Standard_DS2_v2).